# How to set up a managed bean to work with Notes document

Tags: xpages

I would like to set up a managed bean that manages a Notes document in  Notes view where I store application preferences in (e.g. path on server to store attachments, application title, which logo to display etc)
Has anyone an example for such a bean and how I should use it?

Current I load a SSJS library an place everything in application scope or session scope variables.

Answer (score 13):

Here is a simple example for such a managed bean.

First create a Java class. I called it "Config". It reads the first document in view "Config" and puts at instantiation time (=first call) the items in java fields. Doing this you can recycle the domino objects after reading all items and have the values in memory then.

```
package de.leonso;
import java.io.Serializable;
import lotus.domino.Database;
import lotus.domino.Document;
import lotus.domino.View;
import com.ibm.xsp.extlib.util.ExtLibUtil;

public class Config implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;    
    private String applicationTitle;
    // ... other private fields

    public Config() throws NotesException {
        Database db = ExtLibUtil.getCurrentSession().getCurrentDatabase();
        View view = db.getView("Config");
        Document doc = view.getFirstDocument();
        applicationTitle = doc.getItemValueString("ApplicationTitle");
        // ... read all other items and store them in private fields
        doc.recycle();
        view.recycle();
        db.recycle();
    }

    public String getApplicationTitle() {
        return applicationTitle;
    }

    // ... getters for other private fields

}
```

Next define this Java class as a managed bean in faces-config.xml file:

```
<faces-config>
  <managed-bean>
    <managed-bean-name>config</managed-bean-name>
    <managed-bean-class>de.leonso.Config</managed-bean-class>
    <managed-bean-scope>application</managed-bean-scope>
  </managed-bean>
</faces-config>
```

You can use as scope "application" (instance per server) or "session" (instance per user).

Then you can use the config bean in JavaScript:

```
#{javascript:var titel = config.applicationTitle; ...}
```

or Expression Language:

```
#{config.applicationTitle}
```

That should give you a good starting point to develop an advanced version of a config bean.

Comment: This answer looks really good to me.  For some further information there's now several videos on notesjn9.com / XPages.tv in this. Jeremy hodge did a 3 part intro. Russ Maher has some content and I did a "What are Java Beans" show. All are geared for XPages. I have several more shows on this topic coming soon.

Answer (score 0):

The application-scoped bean is definitely a good way to go for this. Once you get more comfortable with Java, you might want to consider using a VariableResolver instead or even an OSGi plugin if some of those options are server-wide. I've also posted an XSnippet for retrieving values from xsp.properties, which may also be appropriate for some settings http://openntf.org/s/retrieve-property-from-xsp.properties-in-nsf-server-or-notes.ini