# Read / Write to Notes document using managed bean in XPages

Tags: xpages

I have set up a managed bean with help of the [following code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17010788/how-to-set-up-a-managed-bean-to-work-with-notes-document/17011684?iemail=1&noredirect=1#17011684).

And have connected inputboxes on an XPage to the managed bean.

Now I want to save values from the inputboxes back to the underlying Notes document.

How should I do this? Should I set up a save method in the managed bean and call it via a button?

Example code would be helpful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In addition to the [code you used](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17011684/2065611) you have to add setters in Java class for all fields you present in inputboxes for change, e.g.

```
public void setApplicationTitle(String applicationTitle) {
    this.applicationTitle = applicationTitle;
}
```

and add a method save()

```
public void save() throws NotesException {
    Database db = ExtLibUtil.getCurrentSession().getCurrentDatabase();
    View view = db.getView("config");
    Document doc = view.getFirstDocument();
    doc.replaceItemValue("ApplicationTitle", applicationTitle);
    // ... replace all other items changed by user
    doc.save(true, true);
    doc.recycle();
    view.recycle();
}
```

and call this method in a button using SSJS

```
#{javascript:config.save()}
```

This is just a starting point for development. In addition, you have to care about possible exceptions. You should also allow changes for admins only as this config document seems to keep general settings for your application.

Comment: Just add a check if the view contains a document when you want to save it and don't recycle the current database

Comment: @stwissel: thanks, deleted db.recycle(). Yes, you're right, handling exceptions or testing if view or doc exists should be added but wanted to keep code short