# Loading a document item values into a map using DataObject in a bean in XPages

Tags: java, xpages, javabeans

I am trying to create a bean that is using the DataObject to collect value from a document.

code is inspired by this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23082652/example-of-how-to-use-a-managed-bean-to-read-write-to-a-configuration-notes-do)

```
package com.consili;
import lotus.domino.*;

import java.util.*;
import com.ibm.xsp.extlib.util.ExtLibUtil;
import java.io.*;
import com.ibm.xsp.model.DataObject;

public class ConfigBean implements DataObject, Serializable { 

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private static HashMap<Object,Object> config = null; 

    public ConfigBean() throws NotesException, IOException, ClassNotFoundException{ 
        config = new java.util.HashMap<Object,Object>(); 
        readFromDocument(); 
    }

    public void readFromDocument() throws NotesException, IOException, ClassNotFoundException{ 
        Database db = ExtLibUtil.getCurrentSession().getCurrentDatabase(); 
        View view = db.getView("Settings"); 
        Document doc = view.getFirstDocument();
        if(doc==null) throw new IllegalArgumentException("doc cannot be null.");
        
        if(doc!=null){
            Iterator<Item> items = doc.getItems().iterator(); 
            while(items.hasNext()){
                Item item =  items.next(); 
                setValue(item.getName(), item.getValueCustomData()); 
            }                 
            doc.recycle(); 
            view.recycle(); 
            db.recycle(); 
        }
    }

    public void saveToDocument(){ 
        //.. write the HashMap back to your document. 
    }

    @Override
    public Object getValue(Object key) {
        if (key == null) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Key cannot be null.");
        } 
        return config.get(key); 
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isReadOnly(Object arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public void setValue(Object key, Object value) {
        
        if (key == null  || value == null) {
               throw new IllegalArgumentException("Key or value cannot be null.");
        } 
        config.put(key.toString(), value); 
    }

    @Override
    public Class<ConfigBean> getType(Object id) {
          return ConfigBean.class;
    }
 }
```

faces-config:

```
 <managed-bean>
    <managed-bean-name>Config</managed-bean-name>
    <managed-bean-class>com.consili.ConfigBean</managed-bean-class>
    <managed-bean-scope>session</managed-bean-scope>
  </managed-bean>
```

the form in the settings doc contain two fields Title and WebUrl
if I add one inputbox to the xpage it throws a class not found exception

javax.faces.FacesException: javax.faces.FacesException: can't create an instanse of the class: 'com.consili.ConfigBean'.. null

```
 <xp:inputText id="inputText1" value="#{Config.Title}"></xp:inputText>
```

I noticed that if I comment out this line

```
 setValue(item.getName(), item.getValueCustomData());
```

the page works and displays the input box, but then the map values would not be be set.

what can be wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I just quickly glanced through your code - and it seems Ok... (or rather, I could not spot the issue either).

Tim Tripcony originally described the same functionality but the repo has been removed. However, I found that Harald Reisinger had put a [copy of it](https://github.com/frocentus/howyabean) on his GitHub :-)

Perhaps you can get a little further by playing with that code? That is the original inspiration to the code that we use ;-)

/John

Answer (score 0):

I looked into this again and it is this line that does not work

```
 setValue(item.getName(), item.getValueCustomData());
```

checking the type and setting the values with correct item types work, like this:

```
if(item.getType() == Item.TEXT){
  setValue(item.getName(), item.getText());
}

if(item.getType() == Item.NUMBERS){
  setValue(item.getName(), item.getValueDouble());
}
```

but this change kind of defeats the purpose of using DataObject which should to my knowledge make the type mapping of data automatically.
Do not really see the point of using DataObject in this way, simple hashmap would have worked just as well.